# xna 4 vertex buffer and vertex declaration for varying triangle count

Tags: c#, windows, xna

I started a project based on the basic effect sample provided by microsoft. Then I appended keys input to move the camera. The final step is to load test 3d data from a DXF file. I wrote the DXF import myself, just simple 3dface objects representing 3d triangles. I adjusted the code in basic effect sample to read the variant vertex count. But I get an error Normal0 missing - even with the vertex declaration and vertex buffer in tact with correctly set vertices. I think the problem is in the vertex declaration. The original sample only have 12 triangles, my first sample DXF has about a thousand.
I think the problem is in here:

```
private void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
vertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[]
    {
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
        new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0),
        new VertexElement(24, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
    }
);
vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(
    graphics.GraphicsDevice,
    vertexDeclaration,
    number_of_vertices,
    BufferUsage.None
    );
Vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[number_of_vertices];
InitializeVerts();
vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(Vertices);
graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
```

}

Vertex Element 12 ... Vertex Element 24 ... Are these the problem areas?

Comment: I just removed the declaration in the cube sample ... this is not the problem .. code works without the dec ... like this ..vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(
graphics.GraphicsDevice,
typeof(VertexPositionNormalTexture),
number_of_vertices,
BufferUsage.None
);

Comment: ... but I still get the Normal0 missing error in the variant vertex project ... I am setting the normal of every vertex to 0,1,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to declare a custom vertex type, then you will not be able to use the `VertexNormalTexture` class as data for your vertex type. You need to create a new struct to hold your data that derives from the `IVertexType` class. Within the structure you then make the vertex declaration available through a method.

You then construct the buffer using your new struct as a parameter to the `Type` field.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976065.aspx).

Comment: :(  I have tried that already. It only works if you do not include light in BassicEffect - which I need. These are not custom vertices they are VertexPositionNormalTexture vertices..
                Vertices[i4] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(v1,

Comment: but if you intend to use `VertexPositionNormalTexture` why bother with making your own `VertexDeclaration`? You can access the vertex declaration for that class using `VertexPositionNormalTexture.VertexDeclaration` as a static member if you need the information in the vertex declaration.